# If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, their cartesian product $X\times Y$ is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZFC set theory, every element object is a set. We know or feel that if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, their cartesian product $X\times Y$ is a set.

My question is: Why if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, their cartesian product $X\times Y$ is a set?

Comment: By definition, the Cartesian product of two sets is the SET of all ordered pairs of blablabla

Comment: @Dante That's not the point of this question.

Answer (score 9):

tldr; $X\times Y$ is a definable subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X \cup Y))$ (assuming that you're using, say, the Kuratowski definition of an ordered pair).

More precisely, suppose $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.  Given the elements $x \in X, y \in Y$, the sets $\{x\}$ and $\{x,y\}$ are in $\mathcal{P}(X \cup Y)$, so the set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X \cup Y))$.  Then define $X\times Y$ to be the set of all sets $z$ in $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X \cup Y))$ such that there are $x,y$ with $z=(x,y)$. You need to do a little bit more than this to actually create a wff in the first-order language of set theory, but not that much more.

For a full wff, we have the following:
$$\varphi(z) = \exists x\exists y\exists v\exists w(x\in X \wedge y\in Y \wedge \mathrm{pair}(v,x,x) \wedge \mathrm{pair}(w,x,y) \wedge \mathrm{pair}(z,v,w))$$
where
$$\mathrm{pair}(z,x,y) = \forall w (w\in z \leftrightarrow ((w=x)\vee (w=y))$$
In other words, $\mathrm{pair}$ is a wff with three free variables which expresses the fact that $z=\{x,y\}$. $\varphi$ expresses that $z$ is itself a pair of elements $v,w$ which are respectively, $v=\{x,x\}=\{x\}$ and $w=\{x,y\}$.  In other words, $z=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.

Then
$$X\times Y = \{ z \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y) \mid \varphi(z)\}$$
(note that $\varphi$ has the parameters $X,Y$).

This uses the Axiom of Power Set, Axiom of Pairing, Axiom of Union,  and the Axiom Schema of Restricted Comprehension.

Why didn't we just say
$$X\times Y = \{ (x,y) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y)) \mid x\in X \wedge y\in Y\}$$
?

Well, recall what the Axiom Schema of Restricted Comprehension actually says: for every set $X$ and every wff $\varphi(x)$ with the free variable $x$, there exists a set $Y$ whose elements are exactly those in $x\in X$ which satisfy $\varphi(x)$. But the aforementioned 'definition' isn't in that form!

How do we normally get away with this, though? Certainly we say things like $\{f(x)\in Y \mid x\in X\}$ for the image of a function $f$! This uses another axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, called the *Axiom Schema of Replacement*.  As shown above, we don't need to use it, and judging from the answer you had written up, it seems you haven't gotten to Replacement yet.

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the edit, for some reason when writing I was just assuming I was showing it for $X\times X$.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether I should give you a heads up about this edit. But since I was certain about what you meant to say, I thought it would be fine. Glad to see that this seems to be the case!

Answer (score 1):

**Proof**. Since $x\in X$, we have $x\in X\cup Y$. Similarly, $y\in X\cap Y$.It follows that the sets {$x$} and {$x,y$} are subsets of $X\cup Y$ and hence elements of $\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y)$. Therefore, {{$x$},{$x,y$}} is a subset of  $\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y)$. Hence, $(x,y)=${{$x$},{$x,y$}}$\in  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y))$ . Thus all the elements of $X\times Y$ are elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y))$. Now among the elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y))$ we will distinguish the ones of the form $(x,y)$ by a formula $\mathcal{P} (z)$, i.e., by a property. In other words, we will find a formula $\mathcal{P} (z)$ such that for all $z$, the following will hold:

$\mathcal{P} (z) \Leftrightarrow \exists x\exists y(x\in X\wedge y\in Y\wedge z=${{$x$},{$x,y$}$)$.

If we can do this, then we will have $X\times Y=$ {$z\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y)):\mathcal{P}(z)$}, and so by A3, $X\times Y$ will be a set.

Comment: Can you check my last proof?

Comment: You shouldn't just create a new answer for each proof attempt; edit your last answer or delete that one.  The only issue with the proof now is that, strictly-speaking, in the language of set theory you cannot write $z=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ in a wff; $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ is not even in the syntax of set theory.  That being said, many people will ignore this, with the understanding that $z=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ is representative of a wff which expresses that $z$ has the indicated form.  If this is homework, you should ask for clarification from your professor about what their expectation is.