# How matrices operations are defined using ZFC axioms?

Tags: matrices, logic, turing-machines

In my algebra book matrices operations looks like a kind of "algorithm". How do matrices operations are defined under ZFC ? Are they applications ? Are they Turing machine ? Are they something else ?

Comment: Look up recursive sets. The μ-recursive functions is exactly the ones computable by a turing machine.

Comment: How Turing machines are defined by sets can be read over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition). But I know (from the other thread) that you actually want to know how this definition gives rise to the function defined by the Turing machine (formally as map in ZFC), a.k.a. the corresponding algorithm, right? Maybe you should include this in the question, the first close vote is dropped for being "too broad".

Comment: Yes, but since i'm french, that is kinda hard for me to express fluently and efficiently !

Comment: the edit made this so much less clear. Are you asking how natural numbers are defined in ZFC ?

Comment: @mercio toto an me had a discussion over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320796/415941). Below my answer the discussion drifted away from the topic. He asked how the concept of algorithm can be implemented in ZFC. He initially wanted to know how this can be done to define matrix multiplication because he only knows about Turing machines, but does not know how they and their defined partial functions emerge in ZFC.

Comment: Hope it makes it more clear, sorry for my bad english

Comment: In you previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320796/construction-of-matrices-under-zfc-axioms) you asked (and received an answer) about "what are matrices": they are *maps*, i.e. *functions*, i.e. *sets*. What is an "operation" on matrices ? A function from matrices to matrices or numbers (e.g. the determinant).

Comment: But, in my algebra book, the "operation" is a kind of algorithm, and it disturb me, since i don't know if an application can act this way. I mean like an algorithm.

Comment: @toto You should really rephrase your question and try to reopen it. If you have problems with the language, then take time or ask for help. For example, it is possible to write a question in another language than english and ask for a translation. To the topic: As I said, algorithms as defined by Turing machines are specially defined (partial) functions. If you want to know how this is done exactly than this should be the main point of your question. Refering to matrix operations etc. will just distract and lead to close votes because it seems like a duplicate.